# how to send http post request using web view only

Tags: android, api, webview, http-post, retrofit

I want to make an http post request using webview.

I'm trying to send post requset to the api server with login credentials and load the response page to the web view and continue to web app from there.

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if (!Common.connectionAvailable(WebActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Check Internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        pd =  new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        pd.setMessage("Loading APP");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);


        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
            );
wv.loadUrl("http://myapp/api/login");
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView object actually has a method to post data using post method

```
String user_id = "USERID";
String user_password = "USER_PASSWORD";

String postData = "username="+user_id+"&password="+user_password;
webView.postUrl("http://localhost/api/login", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

This method is tested and found working in oreo, however, EncodingUtils throws a warning as its deprecated.
any better solution is greatly appreciated.